# ¿Comparar archivos docx en java?

Tags: java

Buen día.

Me surgió una problemática, alguien sabe si es posible en java comparar dos archivos puntualmente archivos docx para saber si tiene diferencias y poder marcar dichas diferencias, algo similar a lo que hace svn subversion?

De antemano muchas gracias

Comment: Los ficheros docx son binarios. Puedes leerlos con poi y luego comparar los documentos. Un coñazo, vamos.

Answer (score 0):

No se mucho de java, pero te puedo encaminar hasta la puerta de ty solución y ya decides si cruzarla.

Con este codigo puedes comparar dos ficheros txt:

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.BufferedReader;

public class Compara
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        try
        {
            BufferedReader lee1 =new BufferedReader(new FileReader("original.txt"));
            BufferedReader lee2 =new BufferedReader(new FileReader("original.txt"));

            String linea1="", linea2 = "";
            System.out.println("Comparando Archivos...");
            int cont1=0, cont2=0;

            while(linea1!=null || linea2!=null)
            {
              linea1=lee1.readLine();
              linea2=lee2.readLine();
              if(linea1!=null){
                  cont1++;
              }
              if(linea2!=null){
                  cont2++;
              }
            };
            System.out.println("Fin de comparacion de los archivos...\n");
            System.out.println("El primer archivo tiene "+cont1+" Lineas");
            System.out.println("El segundo archivo tiene "+cont2+" Lineas");
            if(cont1 == cont2){
                System.out.println("Los archivos comparados son iguales");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Los archivos comparados son diferentes");
            }
            lee1.close();
            lee2.close();
        }
        finally
        {
          System.out.println("fin...");
        }
    }
}
```

Aquí está el código de ReadDoc / docx.java: Esto leerá un archivo dox / docx e imprimirá su contenido en la consola. Puedes personalizarlo a tu manera.

```
 import java.io.*; import org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument; import org.apache.poi.hwpf.extractor.WordExtractor; public class ReadDocFile { public static void main(String[] args) { File file = null; WordExtractor extractor = null; try { file = new File("c:\\New.doc"); FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath()); HWPFDocument document = new HWPFDocument(fis); extractor = new WordExtractor(document); String[] fileData = extractor.getParagraphText(); for (int i = 0; i < fileData.length; i++) { if (fileData[i] != null) System.out.println(fileData[i]); } } catch (Exception exep) { exep.printStackTrace(); } } }
```

Ahora bien, con un poco de organización de organizacion y orden de la sintaxis más un poquito de logica, puedes hacerlo.

Suerte!